# Testing the return value from Mock implementation Setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mstest

I am testing the following class but feel like this may not be the best way.
I could simply test the concrete implementation of the repository class but using Mock for now.

Is this the best approach as in testing the result from the Mock object? Seems a bit redundant to me. How do I test the return from the Mock without using the Object on the Mock to call up the method again?

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected IDbContext<T> dbContext;
    public RepositoryBase(IDbContext<T> dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll()
    {
        return dbContext.GetAll();
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
[TestClass]
public class RepositoryBaseFixture
{
    private Mock<IRepositoryBase<Customer>> _repositoryBase;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void initialize()
    {
        _repositoryBase = new Mock<IRepositoryBase<Customer>>();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var customerList = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "Alvin"},
            new Customer {CustomerId = 2, CustomerName = "Theo"},
            new Customer {CustomerId = 3, CustomerName = "Simon"},
            new Customer {CustomerId = 4, CustomerName = "Jeanette"},
            new Customer {CustomerId = 5, CustomerName = "Eleanor"},
            new Customer {CustomerId = 5, CustomerName = "Brittany"},
        };

        _repositoryBase.Setup(x => x.Insert(customerList));
        _repositoryBase.Setup(x => x.FindAll()).Returns(customerList);

        var result = _repositoryBase.Object.FindAll();

       Assert.AreEqual(customerList, result);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should mock the **dependencies** of the [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test). In your example code you are mocking the same object that you test.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is a test for your mock. As Peter Csala said, you want to mock the dependencies of the class you are testing. This might be a useful test for the maintainers of Moq, but this is pointless for your code base. Instead, test the `RepositoryBase<T>` class, or one of its derived classes.

Looking at the source code for `RepositoryBase<T>`, I really don't see a point in testing that class at all. There is no logic to test, other than it calls through to an IDbContext object. This is so simple I wouldn't bother writing any tests at all.